# How to get cell value in openpyxl versus xlrd?

Tags: python, openpyxl, xlrd

I have the below working code for searching for a keyword in excel files and printing its location:

```
import openpyxl as xl 
import os 
import xlrd

file_extensions = ('.xlsx', '.xlsm', '.xls') 
keyword = 'EUROBUS' 
directory = 'M:\\moje makra'

def filenames(directory): 
    for root, dirs, filenames in os.walk(directory): 
        for filename in filenames: 
            if filename.endswith(file_extensions): 
                yield os.path.join(root, filename) 

for filename in filenames(directory):
    if filename.endswith(file_extensions):
        try:
            wb = xl.load_workbook(filename)
            print('Opened ' + filename)
            for sheet in wb.worksheets: 
                rows = sheet.max_row 
                columns = sheet.max_column
                for row in range(1,rows + 1): 
                    for column in range(1,columns + 1): 
                        if keyword in str(sheet.cell(row=row, column=column).value):
                            print('FOUND IN ' + filename)
                        else:
                            print("NOT FOUND")
        except:
                print('Failed to open ' + filename)
```

However, the openpyxl module does not support .xls format, so I need to rewrite the script to use xlrd instead.

I tried the following:

```
for filename in filenames(directory):
    if filename.endswith(file_extensions):
        try:
            wb = xlrd.open_workbook(filename)
            print('Opened ' + filename)
            for sheet in wb.sheets(): 
                rows = sheet.nrows
                columns = sheet.ncols
                for row in range(1,rows + 1):
                    for column in range(1,column +1):
                        if keyword in str(sheet.cell(row, column).value):
                            print('FOUND IN ' + filename)
                        else:
                            print("NOT FOUND")
        except:
                print('Failed to open ' + filename)
```

But then the code fails to open the workbooks("Opened..." and then "Failed..." for each file gets printed).

I also tried changing `if keyword` line to `str(sheet.cell_value(row,column))`, but to no avail.

How do I fix this?

Comment: If you removed the `try` block, you would get the actual error message, which would help debug this. That's why it's usually not a good idea to put a bunch of code in a `try` block that catch all exceptions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change

```
            for row in range(1,rows + 1):
                for column in range(1,column +1):
```

to

```
            for row in range(rows):  # rows + 1 will result in 'out of range'
                for column in range(columns):  # note 'columns'  not 'column'
```

and remove (or narrow) the `try` block as noted by Mel.